# Solving a System of two ordinary differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:
Solve the following system of differential equations.
\begin{align*}
x' + y' - 2x - 4y &= e^t \tag{1a} \\
x' + y' - y &= e^{4t} \tag{2a} \\
\end{align*}
Answer:
Here I use the operator method.
\begin{align*}
(D-2)x + (D-4)y &= e^t \tag{1b} \\
D(D-2)x + D(D-4)y &= D(e^t) \\
D(D-2)x + D(D-4)y &= e^t \tag{1c} \\
Dx + (D-1)y &= e^{4t} \tag{2b} \\
D(D-2)x + (D-1)(D-2)y &= (D-2)(e^{4t}) = 4e^{4t} - 2e^{4t} \\
D(D-2)x + (D-1)(D-2)y &= 2e^{4t} \tag{2c} \\
D(D-4)y - (D-1)(D-2)y  &= e^t - 2e^{4t} \\
(D^2 - 4D)y - (D^2 - 3D + 2)y &= e^{t} - 2e^{4t} \\
(D^2 - 4D - D^2 + 3D - 2)y &= e^{t} - 2e^{4t} \\
(-D - 2)y &= e^t - 2e^{4t} \\
\frac{dy}{dt} + 2y &= 2e^{4t} - e^t \\
\end{align*}
Now, we have a first order ordinary differential equation. We now find the integrating factor $I$.
\begin{align*}
I &= e^{\int 2 \, dt} = e^{2t} \\
e^{2t}\frac{dy}{dt} + 2e^{2t}y &= 2e^{6t} - e^{3t} \\
D( e^{2t}y) &= 2e^{6t} - e^{3t} \\
e^{2t}y &= \frac{e^{6t}}{3} - \frac{e^{3t}}{3} + C \\
y &= \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} + Ce^{-2t} \\
\end{align*}
Now we have to solve for $x$.
\begin{align*}
y' &= \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 2Ce^{-2t} \\
x' + \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 2Ce^{-2t} - \left( \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} + Ce^{-2t} \right) &= e^{4t} \\
x' + \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 2Ce^{-2t} - \left( \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} + Ce^{-2t} \right) &= 0 \\
x' - \frac{e^t}{3} - 2Ce^{-2t} - \left(  - \frac{e^t}{3} + Ce^{-2t} \right) &= 0 \\
x' &= -3Ce^{-2t} \\
x &= \frac{3Ce^{-2t}}{2} + C_2 \\
\end{align*}
Now we use the equation $x' + y' - 2x - 4y = e^t$ to eliminate one of the constants. Since no initial conditions were given,
we cannot eliminate both constants.
\begin{align*}
-3Ce^{-2t} + y' - 2\left( x \right)  - 4y &= e^t \\
-3Ce^{-2t} + \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 2Ce^{-2t} - 2\left( \frac{3Ce^{-2t}}{2} + C_2 \right)
 - 4\left( \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} + Ce^{-2t} \right)  &= e^t \\
-5Ce^{-2t} + \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 2\left( \frac{3Ce^{-2t}}{2} + C_2 \right)
- 4\left( \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} + Ce^{-2t} \right)  &= e^t \\
%
-5Ce^{-2t} + \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 3Ce^{-2t} - 2 C_2 
- 4\left( \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} + Ce^{-2t} \right)  &= e^t \\
%
-8Ce^{-2t} + \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 3Ce^{-2t} - 2 C_2 
- 4\left( \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} \right)  &= e^t \\
%
-8Ce^{-2t} + \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 3Ce^{-2t} - 2 C_2 - \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} + \frac{4e^t}{3}  &= e^t \\
-11Ce^{-2t} + \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 2 C_2 - \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} + \frac{4e^t}{3}  &= e^t \\
-11Ce^{-2t}  - \frac{e^t}{3} - 2 C_2 + \frac{4e^t}{3}  &= e^t \\
-2 C_2 &= 0 \\
C_2 &= 0 \\
-11C &= 0 \\
C_0 &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
This does not seem right to me.  Hence, my answer is:
\begin{align*}
x &= 0 \\
y &= \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3}  \\
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{3ce^{-2t}}{2} \\
y &=  -\frac{2ce^{-2t}}{3} + \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3}  \\
\end{align*}
What did I do wrong?

Comment: You must have a sign error in the last group of equations, as you should obtain $0\,C=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I suspect you are right about the sign error but I cannot find it. Do you know where it is? If so, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my correct solution to find $x$:

\begin{align*}
-2x - 4y + y &= e^t - e^{4t} \\
-2x - 3y &= e^t - e^{4t} \\
-2x &= e^t - e^{4t} + 3y \\
-2x &= e^t - e^{4t} + 3 \left(  -\frac{2ce^{-2t}}{3} + \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3}   \right) \\
-2x &= e^t - e^{4t} - 2ce^{-2t} + e^{4t} - e^t \\
-2x &= -2ce^{-2t} \\
x &= ce^{-2t} \\
\end{align*}

Now, I am matching the book.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z:=x+y$ and the system turns to

$$\begin{cases}z'-2z-2y=e^t,\\z'-y=e^{4t}.\end{cases}$$

Then eliminating $y$,

$$z'+2z=2e^{4t}-e^t,$$ has the solution

$$z=Ce^{-2t}+\frac13e^{4t}-\frac13e^t.$$

Then you draw $y$ from 
$$y=z'-e^{4t}=-2Ce^{-2t}+\frac13e^{4t}-\frac13e^t$$ and $x=z-x$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
  x'+y'-2x-4y &= e^t \tag{1} \\
  x'+y'-y &= e^{4t} \tag{2} \\
\end{align}

$(2)-(1)$ gives,
$$  2x+3y = e^{4t}-e^{t} \tag{3}$$

$(2)\times 2-(1)$ gives,
$$(x+y)'+2(x+y) = 2e^{4t}-e^t \tag{4}$$

Solving $(4)$ gives,

$$x+y=\frac{e^{4t}-e^t}{3}+ke^{-t} \tag{5}$$

Can you proceed?

If you've learn't matrices in linear algebra course, you may refer to this link [*here*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation).

Comment: Is my approach wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there'll be extraneous solution coming out when you differentiate on the equations.  Also, I'm not quite follow how to arrive $(-D-2)y=e^t-2e^{4t}$.

Comment: @Nu Chung Tak I added an extra line to show more detail. Now, can you see how I got $(-D - 2)y = e^t - 2e^{4t}$?

Comment: One term (in red) is missing:
$$-8Ce^{-2t} + \frac{4e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3} - 3Ce^{-2t} - 2 C_2 
- 4\left( \frac{e^{4t}}{3} - \frac{e^t}{3}+\color{red}{Ce^{-2t}} \right)  = e^t$$